# Getting error when dynamically assiging array to a key in a hash

Tags: powershell

I have a third party function which creates a profile for a server. When I create an array and assign to hash that is required by third party function it is working fine, but when I dynamically create an array and assign it I am getting error.

Have tried working with simple variable that has all values and have created and array also of these values statically. But when I dynamically create it fails.

```
Function New-Disk
{
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Array] $XXX_drivedata
    )
    if ($XXX_drivedata[3] -ieq "yes")
    {
        $boot_data = $TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $boot_data = $FALSE;
    }
    if ($XXX_drivedata[9] -ieq "yes")
    {
        $erase_data = $TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $erase_data = $FALSE;
    }
    $params1 = @{
        name = $XXX_drivedata[0];
        RAID = $XXX_drivedata[1];
        numberofDrives = $XXX_drivedata[2];
        driveType = $XXX_drivedata[5];
        driveSelectionBy = $XXX_drivedata[6];
        minDriveSize = $XXX_drivedata[7];
        maxDriveSize = $XXX_drivedata[8];
        eraseDataOnDelete = $erase_data;
        bootable = $boot_data;
        accelerator = $XXX_drivedata[4];
        storageLocation = $XXX_drivedata[10]
    }


$params = $params1.Clone()
    foreach($item in $params1.GetEnumerator())
    {
        #if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($item.Value) -or ($item.Value -ieq "null"))
        if (!$item.value)
        {
            $params.Remove($item.Key)
        }
    }
    try {
        $logical_disk_create = New-<Function for disk> @params
        if ($logical_disk_create)
        {
            $XXX_disk_create_status = "pass"
            return $SCID_disk_create_status,$logical_disk_create.SasLogicalJBOD
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error $_
        $XXX_disk_create_status = "fail"
        return $XXX_disk_create_status,$logical_disk_create
        continue
    }
}

#------------------------------------------------
#Attach local disk and JBOD to controller
#------------------------------------------------

Function New-Controller
{
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Array] $SCID_controller_detail,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Array] $SCID_logicaldisk_detail
    )
    if ($SCID_controller_detail[1] -ieq "yes")
    {
        $initialize_data = $TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $initialize_data = $FALSE;
    }
    $params1 = @{controllerID = $XXX_controller_detail[0];initialize = $initialize_data;writeCache = $XXX_controller_detail[2];logicalDisk = $XXX_logicaldisk_detail}

    $params = $params1.Clone()
    foreach($item in $params1.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if ($item.key -ne "logicalDisk")
        {
            #if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($item.Value))
            if (!$item.value)
            {
                $params.Remove($item.Key)
            }
        }
    }
    try {

        $logicaldisk_controller_create = New-<Function for disk controller> @params
        if ($logicaldisk_controller_create)
        {
            $SCID_disk_create_status = "pass"
            return $SCID_disk_create_status,$logicaldisk_controller_create
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error $_
        $SCID_disk_create_status = "fail"
        return $SCID_disk_create_status,$logicaldisk_controller_create
        continue
    }
}

#--------------------------------------------------
#Create Server Profile
#--------------------------------------------------

Function New-ServerProfile
{

        .......

    #------------------------------------------------------
    #Read local disk and JBOD details
    #------------------------------------------------------

    $SP_logical_disk_list = @()
    $SP_logical_disk_list_controller = @()
    $XXX_controllerdata = @("$($serverprofile.localStorages.integratedStorageController.controllerID)", "$($serverprofile.localStorages.integratedStorageController.reinitialize)", "$($serverprofile.localStorages.integratedStorageController.writeCache)")

    if ($serverprofile.localStorages.integratedStorageController.logicalDrive)
    {
        foreach ($logicaldrive in $($serverprofile.localStorages.integratedStorageController.logicalDrive))
        {
            $XXX_drivedata = @("$($logicaldrive.name)", "$($logicaldrive.raidLevel)", "$($logicaldrive.physicalDrives)", "$($logicaldrive.boot)", "$($logicaldrive.accelarator)", "$($logicaldrive.driveTechnology)")
            $logicaldisk_create = New-Disk -XXX_drivedata $XXX_drivedata
            if ($logicaldisk_create[0] -ne "fail")
            {
                $SP_logical_disk_list += $logicaldisk_create[1]
                $XXX_drivedata.Clear()
            }
        }
        $logdisk_controller = New-Controller -XXX_controller_detail $SCID_controllerdata -XXX_logicaldisk_detail $SP_logical_disk_list
        if ($logdisk_controller[0] -ne "fail")
        {
            $SP_logical_disk_list_controller += $logdisk_controller[1]
        }
    }

...........................

$LogicalDisk = New-<Fuctionfordisk> -Name "MyDisk" | New-<Function for disk controller> -Initialize
    $LogicalDisks = New-<Fuctionfordisk> -Name "MyDisk" | New-<Function for disk controller> -Initialize
    $logcaldr = @($LogicalDisk, $LogicalDisks)

$params1 = @{
        ....................
                other parameters

        logicalDisk = $SP_logical_disk_list_controller
    }
    $params = $params1.Clone()
    foreach($item in $params1.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if ($item.key -ne "LogicalDisk|localStorage")
        {
            #if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($item.Value) -or ($item.Value -ieq "null"))
            if (!$item.value)
            {
                $params.Remove($item.Key)
            }
        }
    }
    $task = New-<Server Profile> @params | Wait-<task>
```

When I use localdr it is working fine but when I use `$SP_logical_disk_list_controller` for Storage I am getting error

> The JSON sent in the request contained a unknown type where a different unknown type was required on line 1 near column 746. Correct the content of the JSON and try the request again.

I have even tried using `$logdisk_controller[1]` but still same error comes.

Comment: Does `New-<Server Profile>` contain a call to `ConvertTo-Json` perhaps? Make sure it specifies an appropriate `-Depth`

Comment: The code you posted is both incomplete and broken. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, test run that sample code to make sure it actually exposes the problem, then [edit] your question and copy/paste that code along with the full error message you got from that code.

Comment: Depth is given as -depth 99. Does it requires an increase

Comment: Certain parts which I have not included have nothing to do with code not working (if logicaldisk key is omitted code works for rest of keys). I can not post everything that is written but have posted where I am facing issue

Comment: You're not required to post your full code. You *are* required to post a [mcve], though. Your chances of people being able to help you significantly decrease when the code you post does not allow us to reproduce the problem or introduces additional errors.